# What module should I use for high precision localization?

Tags: gps, robotics, distance

I have a toy car and I want to measure the coordinates/location of that car in my house.

It need to bee high precision equipment so GPS won't work here.

My precision requriments is 5+- cm and the distance is like 10-20 meters as maximum raduis.

What module should I use then?

Comment: you could mount cameras to the walls and track the object optically

Comment: @jsotola that won't work for me. It need to be very like GPS, but local.

Comment: While there certainly are systems, that work like a local GPS, they will be very expensive and most likely not easy to use. Honestly I wouldn't know, where I would be able to source such a system. Please explain more about the requirements. Why won't cameras work for you?

Comment: @chrisl because cameras can't see through walls.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson So much I already thought. Please add a description of your general goal and setup to your question. I don't think, that a "local GPS" is really a viable option here. But maybe - when we know your setup and requirements - we can suggest different sensors (or maybe a combination of sensors)

Comment: there is no "module" you can use. Heck, there's not really _anything_ you can use with an Arduino. There's a few systems that do things like this, though not to that level of precision, and those are lab-based proof of concepts more than working systems. Ultrasonic triangulation might be your best bet fi you can lower the precision requirements a notch or two, but even that's complex AF.

Comment: @dandavis Thank you. I think I have to quit my idea then if it's not possible to have a high precision Local Position System inside my house.

Comment: @chrisl I don't know my setup or requriments, except it need be small, have 4 wheels and have a precision about 5+- cm. That's all I need.